# Graceful leadership transition in Solr 6.3 and Zookeeper 3.4

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, sharding, leader

Is there a way to initiate a graceful transition of leadership when using a sharded index in Solr 6.3 with Zookeeper 3.4?

Thus far the team simply stops the Solr process for the leader. Zookeeper observes the down node and elects the replica.

That doesn't seem very graceful. I'm looking for something like rs.stepDown() in Mongo.